# MySQL inserts on March 09th fail due to DST

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, utc

I have a Java program which uses Spring JPA that logs events to a MySQL table.

In the entity class, I have defined the timestamp attribute as below:

```
@Column("received_timestamp")
private Instant receivedTimestamp;
```

The datatype of `received_timestamp` is `TIMESTAMP`.

Before inserting into DB I am converting the timestamp in the event I receive from EST to an instance of `java.time.Instant`. When I debug, I can see that, this converts the received time to UTC.

Events received between 09PM and 10PM on the 09th of March 2024, have failed with the error `Incorrect datetime value`.

My MySQL server is in the timezone EST/EDT.

My theory is that although I sent UTC timestamps to MySQL, it assumed that I am sending timestamps in EST and tried to convert it to UTC. E.g.: an event received at 09:30PM EST would be converted to 02:30AM by my application. MySQL, thinking 02:30AM is in EDT, tries to convert it to UTC but it fails because 02:30AM EDT is not a valid time.

Could someone please validate this theory.

Comment: `Instant` is not mapped to any SQL type in JDBC. For table columns of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, that maps to the Java class `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: @BasilBourque thanks for the reply! I got your point. So in my case, would the theory I suggested be the cause of the SQL errors during the DST window?